# Adding window.scrollTo to simple jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can't figure out how to get this to work. I've tried a few variations. I want the window to scroll to top of `.accordion > dt` based on it's offset. Currently this code just opens the panel and starts reloading the page.

```
(function($) {

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var allPanels = $j('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > a > dt').click(function() {
        $this = $j(this);
        $target = $this.parent().next();
        

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
            $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
            window.scrollTo($(".accordion").offset().top);
        }

        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your `DT` elements reside with anchor tags. By returning false you are stopping the default click behavior on the `DT` element, however, you still need to stop the event from propagating up to the link.

```
$('.accordion > a > dt').click(function(e) {

    $this = $j(this);
    $target = $this.parent().next();


    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
        $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
        window.scrollTo($(".accordion").offset().top);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I copy and pasted this in and it doesn't seem to be working. In firefox it reloads the page and in Safari, it jumps to the right and the accordion panel that was clicked isn't at the top. Should I do anything other than replacing this code with mine?

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample HTML, or work off of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqr5C/

Comment: It works great in jsfiddle but when I try to implement it in my code it doesn't work, I even tried a simple plain HTML doc with all the aspects of the fiddle you set up and it didn't work. Then I went to the "panels" table on the left of the jsfiddle page and changed "javascript" to javascript 1.7" and the 1.7 version shows the result I'm getting. I'm using the google jquery link to 1.7.2

Also my html goes:
<dl class="accordion">
  <a href="">panel name</a>
     <dd>panel content</dd>
</dl>

Thanks for your help so far!